# Python port scanner, how to determine optimal number of threads

Tags: python, multithreading, port-scanning

I have a multi threaded Python port scanner where each thread in a loop gets something (an IP address/port pair) from a common queue, does some work on it (connects, does a handshake and grabs the server's version) and loops again.

Here's some partial code:

```
import threading, queue, multiprocessing

class ScanProcess(multiprocessing.Process):
    threads = []

    def __init__(self, squeue, dqueue, count):
        self.squeue = squeue
        self.dqueue = dqueue
        self.count = count
        self._init_threads()
        super(ScanProcess, self).__init__()

    def _init_threads(self):
        self.threads = [ScanThread(self.squeue, self.dqueue) for _ in range(0, self.count)]

    def _start_threads(self):
        for thread in self.threads:
            thread.start()

    def _join_threads(self):
        for thread in self.threads:
            thread.join()

    def run(self):
        self._start_threads()
        self._join_threads()

class ScanThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, squeue, dqueue):
        self.squeue = squeue
        self.dqueue = dqueue
        super(ScanThread, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        while not self.squeue.empty():
            try:
                target = self.squeue.get(block=False)
                # do the actual work then put the result in dqueue
            except queue.Empty:
                continue

# how many threads/processes
process_count = 2
thread_count = 10

# load tasks from file or network and fill the queues
squeue = multiprocessing.Queue()
dqueue = multiprocessing.Queue()

# create and start everything
processes = [ScanProcess(squeue, dqueue, thread_count) for _ in range(0, process_count)]

for process in processes:
    process.start()

for process in processes:
    process.join()

# enjoy the show!
```

The problem I've got is that the number of threads is currently set manually. I'd like to set it automatically to saturate the network connection while not dropping packets, but I have no idea how to begin implementing that. Could anyone summarize how nmap/zmap do it?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Not an answer, but I like your user name and I'm surprised you got it.

Comment: @nicomp I believe usernames are not unique here so you can have the same as well ;)